# Computer Beeps 3 Times on Startup

Tags: boot

I am experiencing a really annoying problem right now. I am experiencing times when my PC just shuts down, then when I turn it on, I am greeted with 3 continuous beeps over and over.

Comment: the beeps usually have a specific meaning, but that depends on the mainboard

Comment: What research have you done into this issue?  What make, what model?  Have you looked at the user manual for the PC, which usually describes what the startup beeps mean?

Answer (score 2):

It really is hard to tell without your actual motherboard make and model however here is a general guideline. First of all it is always good to hook up the little black speaker that comes with your motherboard as it solves so many problems that you can't see from the display.

[image]

**AMI BIOS beep codes**

[image]

**Award Bios beep codes**

[image]

**Dell Bios beep codes**

[image]

**IBM Bios beep codes**

[image]

**Macintosh Bios beep codes**

[image]

**Phoenix Bios beep codes**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Credit: https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

Answer (score 0):

These beeps are the rudimentary feedback system implemented by your motherboard's [Power-On Self-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) or POST. It is a quick diagnostic that your computer performs to make sure it has everything it needs to make it through the booting process. If there are any errors, it will provide you audible feedback (the beeps) that can be used to look up the error in your motherboard's documentation.

Make note of whether they are quick, short blips or elongated bleeps (think Morse code). Look up the model number of your motherboard and search for `<mobo model> post beep codes`. That should get you pretty far in your search.

Future readers: this is why your motherboard came with that itty bitty plastic speaker with two wires and a tiny connector. It's important to plug it in!