# Custom PC with ASUS Z87-PRO locked in POST loop

Tags: boot, motherboard, post

I have built this custom PC with an ASUS Z87-PRO 4 years ago. I have been using it since without much problem. I have upgraded some components over the years like the hard disks without any issue.

Yesterday, I removed the speakers system for a party. I came back to my PC, plugged in the speakers system back and powered on to find out that it was stuck in a POST loop. [You can see a short video of the Q-Code LED information I'm getting](https://youtu.be/9d6aazVWAF8). No single 2-digi error code stays on. They just keep rotating in this loop.

I can also see the VGA led, the CPU led and the DRAM led lighting up for a fraction of a second in this POST loop in this sequence: VGA, CPU, DRAM. I'm guessing POST is testing them when the led light is up. I'm also guessing these components are fine since the led doesn't stay up as well.

There was a storm this morning but I doubt this is an issue here. My PC is plugged into an APC Back-UPS Pro 1000 which should take care of power spike issues.

While I'm in the POST loop, my monitors do not show anything. They just remain black.

How can I start my investigation to solve this issue?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unplug everything except the essentials.. so motherboard, memory, power, keyboard, mouse, display (assuming onboard video). See how far you get in your boot process then add hard drive back in. Basically try parts out to narrow down the culprit. You could also hook up an internal speaker to get a beep code as well which would be most helpful https://superuser.com/questions/1324729/computer-beeps-3-times-on-startup/1324740#1324740

Comment: First, do as Eric said above.  `There was a storm this morning but I doubt this is an issue here. My PC is plugged into an APC Back-UPS Pro 1000 which should take care of power spike issues.` Ehhh I think you have too much trust into your UPS, they can only do so much. That being said, if something did get fried, your UPS has a equipment protection policy. You would have to contact APC to figure out more details.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue by removing the various components and trying to POST again. I found out this was related to PCI Express. Disabling gen3 on pci_lane1 for my graphics card and forcing gen2 solved this issue.

However, I believe this is a motherboard defect. After reading various forums and user problems around, it seems like this have been happening to many other people using the same motherboard.

The degraded PCI Express lane is a bummer and I'm likely to switch motherboard.

Comment: Today I am getting this too. Black monitors even with nothing plugged in. Probably time to replace the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

I know this subject is old enough, BUT (!) since I faced the same problems with a second hand Asus p8z68 gen3
I have in my hands a few months now, I would like to share the knowledge I actually got from someone else.
So my problem with this mobo was that sometimes it was posting fine, then other times again it was stuck during the diagnostic procedure
to the VGA led. This led when post stuck, remains always on and also you can hear a beep code coming from the mobo. (One long and three short beeps)
So first of all. This mobo has some switches on it. Specifically it has a small button switch "MemOK! switch" called in the manual and I quote:

"If your system fail to boot due to BIOS overclocking, press the MemOK! switch to boot
and load BIOS default settings. A message will appear during POST reminding you
that the BIOS has been restored to its default settings."

I know that your problem is not coming from overclocking at this point but since our target is to pass the diagnostic tests on mobo to the point that we can get into the BIOS
lets try the default reset settings with this button first!

I you manage to pass from this point, the next one would be to get into the BIOS, go to CPU Configuration settings and rolling down find and DISABLE C3 and C6 Reports.
Those reports did the job for me!
After a long time of frustration with this MOBO and A LOT of resets, it is fully functional again!
Hope that all this will help someone out there.
Take care guys.